# Heroku only allows the client who is developer's machine to access websocket application

Tags: java, gwt, heroku, websocket

I developed an application using Heroku, written by java, GWT, embedded tomcat and websocket. I tested it in local, everything is fine.

But when I deployed it to Heroku server, only the computer where I developed this app and use my account is able to access this app fully functionally, the rest computers except mine can only load html pages, but for the websocket call, those computers only get 404 response.

Looks like Heroku restricts the IPs that can access this app.

Any ideas?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Heroku does not restrict IPs, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that wss and ws do the trick.

Weird, though.